# How to change cells to currency

Tags: excel, vba

Database software system exports reports on Excel. Report sheet then gets inserted into a work book, copy paste.  Totals have decimals, after I select entire column for converting "totals" column into currency format "$", excel will not make include dollar symbol changes unless I multiply cell number by 1.

Is there another solution besides the following?

Example:

Cell `A1`:

```
=10,000.00*1

=$10,000.00
```

Comment: when it import it is importing as a string.  By doing the math it is being forced to a number.  You can do the same using text to columns.

Comment: Looks like the numbers are pasted in with their thousands separators, which may or may not match the character Excel is using for this. Have the database export output unformatted numbers, and set the destination cells' `NumberFormat` to `"Currency"`. The cell's *value* (as it appears in the formula bar) should read `10000`, not `10,000.00`; the number formatting is responsible for maknig the cells' *text* (as it appears on the worksheet) read `$10,000.00`

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon - Thank you, positive reply.  However, after DB exports, I get the numbers listed such as, 727.16, Legacy Database can not be adjusted for export output with unformatted numbers.

Comment: Is the source a *view* or something? If so, you could connect the worksheet to the db and write your own SELECT statement that ensures numeric values are output as numbers. Otherwise... go with Scott's solution =)

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon -   Yes source is a view.

Comment: Good, then you can connect to it through the DATA Ribbon, and make a SELECT statement that selects from that view and casts the number-as-text values into actual numbers - do you know whata database engine you're dealing with? Are you familiar with SQL on any level?

Comment: e.g. if the view has columns `foo` and `bar`, and is named `foobars`, you can get the records with `SELECT foo, bar FROM foobars` - and if `bar` is the number-as-text column, you should be able to cast it like `SELECT foo, bar=CAST(bar AS DECIMAL(18,6)) FROM foobars` (assuming SQL Server; different db engines might have different syntaxes).

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon -  I utilize SSMS, front end.

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon - I am receiving the export from legacy system, not able to use DB for this flat file set as export Excel.

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon - I just ran it through Access and yes numbers can be changed to currency when export into Excel from Access.

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon -   Utilized DATA ribbon, get Data, File Workbook, then it does change text numbers into currency.  However, this would be okay for me, not for the macro process, or is there a Macro that will automate besides me recording step by step process as my described process?

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon - Thank you!

Comment: If your source is a view then you can just connect to it and no macro needs to get involved, next week you just right-click and refresh and poof done! ...unless I'm missing something. Power Query can help too ("Get & Transform")

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon - will review my Excel data sources, then see what process is most efficient with processes.